# How to create a custom controller with user authentication - Odoo13?

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I am trying to create a custom controller with user authentication.
Here is what i did.

```
class GetUserDetails(http.Controller):
@http.route('/web/getUserDetail',auth='user',type='json')
def getChit(self,**kw):
    print('Inside getUser detail',kw)
```

Issue 1: When i call this controller from an API client (ARC) its directly get into that function, without any authentication.???

Issue 2: If we solved the above issue, how can i authenticate a user via API call/client.

Actually i want to get user details in android app.

Comment: The controller could be overridden somewhere to set `auth` to public or you are already logged.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Odoo controller using cookie for authentication. So if you call API from other apps/device, better to use Odoo webservice API [https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/webservices/odoo](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/webservices/odoo.)

Odoo webservice API already integrated with "Access Rights" or "Record Rule", so IMO this is the best way to connecting Odoo with other apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *[REST Framework](https://github.com/OCA/rest-framework)* for Odoo to create your API and do the authentication (see [#13](https://github.com/OCA/rest-framework/pull/13) for more details), or you can use *[JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token)*